# Connecting to unknown number of databases using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am writing a ruby script that needs to connect to a primary database in order to retrieve a list of secondary databases to connect to. The steps I need to carry out are:

1. Connect to primary DB
2. Retrieve list of secondary databases to connect to
3. Iterate through list of secondary databases, extracting a single model from each database

I don't need to be connected to multiple secondary databases at once, so open -> retrieve object -> close is fine.

All of the examples I have seen so far describe multiple connections where the databases are described in database.yml, which is not possible here as the number of databases I need to connect to can vary.

This [blog post](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2011/10/20/connection-management-in-activerecord.html) describes using a connection pool as follows:

```
spec = database_a
ActiveRecord::ConnectionPool.open(spec) do |conn|
  User.find_all
end

spec = database_b
ActiveRecord::ConnectionPool.open(spec) do |conn|
  User.find_all
end
```

However, `ConnectionPool` seems to have changed and the `.open` method no longer exists.

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What version of Ruby/Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm curious why you wouldn't use SQL to satisfy the replication, e.g. triggers to update the master table? You might not even need ruby to be involved. A SQL solution would be much faster

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with this:

```
[1] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::ConnectionPool
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionPool
```

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionPool` doesn't exist.  However, on my journey to find it, I found [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb), which looks like something that you want.